# Текст градиентом и тенью

Tags: css, градиент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать такой текст? Сам текст залит градиентом + бордер сделан градиентом переходящий от красного в прозрачный.

Answer (score 1):

Это работает только в Webkit браузерах.

```css
h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FE0, #800);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>BURN</h1>
```